# How to get results for a specific country/region only, via Google AJAX Search or Custom Search APIs?

Tags: ajax, search

I just want to specify a region and a search phrase, and retrieve the URLs of the top 10 result pages for that search phrase/region from Google...

Answer (score 1):

Add &gl=country_code to the request URL

Example:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=music&gl=in